# Allow bluetooth devices to wake PC

Tags: windows, bluetooth, sleep

I have a bluetooth mouse and keyboard attached to my Windows 10 desktop. However neither of these devices are able to wake the computer from sleep and no guide online appears accurate.
Does anyone know if and how this can be configured?

Comment: Marking an answer as accepted that does not solve the problem? Is that correct what you said? Marking an answer as accepted indicates it resolved the problem and others will not likely chime in that have a solution just so you know. You don't have to assume, either provided solutions work for your question or they do not. From admin elevated command prompt, type in `powercfg hibernate off`... now with the suggested advice from harry, give it another shot. Don't be intimidated by high reputation answerers, if something does not work, have answerers dig more for you and please don't assume.

Comment: Also, sometimes it might take days for someone with a solution to come along and help. But if you have it marked as complete, it is safe to assume the question got an answer that resolved the problem. You are not doing yourself any favors by accepting answers that do not resolve your question which is what this site is about. If there's an answer that resolves for other but not yours, that is great and you can upvote it and so can others. But I hope you understand what I'm trying to convey here with great respect too. Respectfully~

Comment: True. I did jump the gun. Part of my thinking was also related to the fact their answer included all of the other information I had found myself during my fairly exhausting search online for a solution. I also read that this functionality is not included in all bluetooth devices as a choice from manufactures, as it wastes power and is seldom needed, hence why the power configuration field is not present for all devices. I will unmark the answer based on your reasoning for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Enable device Wake-on-Bluetooth**

- Connect the Bluetooth device
- Run Device Manager
- Double-click Bluetooth
- Double-click the specific device (*not the Bluetooth adapter!*)
- Click the "Power Management" tab
- Click to check "Allow this device to wake the computer"
- Click OK
- Reboot.

If the device doesn't have a "Power Management" tab, perhaps the
following can still help.

**Disable hibernate**

In general, the Bluetooth device will be disconnected when the system
enters sleep or hibernate mode, so cannot wake up the computer.

However, if Modern Standby is supported, the Bluetooth devices are
still connected
after the system enters sleep mode. But if it enters hibernate mode,
the connection will be disabled.

Here is how to enable Modern Standby:

- In the Start menu, run "Choose a power plan"
- Click "Change plan settings" for your power plan
- Click "Change advanced power settings"
- Expand "Hibernate after", located under "Sleep"
- Set "On battery" and "Plugged in" as "Never"
- Click OK
- Reboot.

If this doesn't work still, the chances are slim, but continue on.

**Last-ditch effort**

- Run Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator
- Enter the command: `powercfg /devicequery wake_programmable`
- If you see the Bluetooth device in the list, run

  ```
    powercfg /deviceenableawake "Bluetooth Device exact name"
  ```

  *Note*: The above command is worded according to the documentation
  with [deviceenableawake](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options#option_deviceenablewake).
  However, the help shown by `powercfg /?` says rather that the
  verb is `deviceenablewake`:

  ```
   powercfg /deviceenablewake "Bluetooth Device exact name"
  ```
- Run the command:

  ```
    powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
  ```

  If your device is now in the list, this should now work. Reboot.

If nothing works, then the computer hardware probably does not
support Wake-on-Bluetooth.

Comment: Sadly none of these work for me. I assume this answer is complete, but Im going to give more time for anyone else to chime in before I mark it as such.

Comment: There's a typo, Last-ditch command should be `powercfg /deviceenablewake "Bluetooth Device exact name"`

Comment: @G-Wiz: Seems like a documentation error. I have added a note to my post about this discrepancy.

Comment: When running `powercfg` in the command prompt as an administrator, I get "You do not have permission to enable or disable device wake". Does this actually mean I have a permissions problem or just that my hardware does not support wake-on-bluetooth?

Comment: @hughes: The CMD must be started with "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score -1):

It looks like most Wifi+bluetooth addon PCIe adapters simply do not support hardware-based BT key storing, which is required when the OS with its BT driver is sleeping. There maybe some adapters or USB dongles with such feature, but you rather find this feature on high class laptops.