# Bluetooth card vs dongle

Tags: windows, drivers, bluetooth

I used to have a bluetooth keyboard, with a Windows PC and a USB bluetooth dongle, but sometimes I was unable to use the keyboard to unlock the computer - it was like the PC needed to wait for Windows to be unlocked before loading the bluetooth drivers or something. It was weird, as it didn't happen every time, but it became such a problem that I got rid of the keyboard after a few weeks.

I'm wondering if a bluetooth card installed inside the PC would avoid this issue or whether it would be the same.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Do you have Wake-on-Bluetooth turned on? see [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1626611) for more details.

Comment: It's hard to say without further testing, as this isn't necessarily caused by the BT, it could also be a power-state issue, etc.  And which version of Windows do you have?

Comment: If Bluetooth is built in (2 machines here like that), Bluetooth is one of the first things loaded so (a) my mouse works immediately and (b) your keyboard will work right away.

Comment: Thanks all, I think wake-on-bt was enabled as that was one of the first things I checked, but it was a while back now (pre-pandemic) so I can't be 100%.

It's Windows 10.

The mobo (Asus hero maximus XI) does not have BT built in, but I am thinking/hoping PCI-E card may be a bit more reliable than USB dongle?