# How to identify Bluetooth adapters support WakeUp Windows PC from sleep on a keyboard or mouse action?

Tags: bluetooth, sleep, adapter, wake-up

Even in Windows XP you could find a message in the log, like "this BT adapter does not support storing keys and wake up is not possible".

Okay, so knowing that, what kind/model/brand of adapter on the market exactly supports that, and is able to wake up the PC from sleep (S3 state, etc) on a keyboard or mouse action?

As far as I know, Intel Wireless AC WiFi boards with add-on USB Bluetooth chip do not support that. Even when USB offline power/charge is available.

However, some Intel NUCs *do* support the feature with onboard Bluetooth.

So, who makes the wakeup capable Bluetooth adapters and how can they be identified by a consumer?

Comment: Personally, I do not like how the title was edited. It may be gramatically correct, but got inhuman flavor, almost breaking your mind... "how to identify."  Simply: "what adapters do support?" Is it that provocative?

Comment: Thats crazy. Either no-one sees point behind the edited title, or no-one needs a wake-up feature from Bluetooth inputs. I can't believe that.

Comment: Maybe that helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1626566/allow-bluetooth-devices-to-wake-pc

Comment: No. Thats completely different. That is about ENABLING. But before enabling, you need an adapter capable of listening for BT devices with sleeping OS. However there is no information, what king of adapter that is, no practical examples. But there is obviously a capability in MS driver. So they had tested it at least 15 years ago with some very real equipment.

Comment: @asdf the title asked us for a list of hardware, which is against the rules of this site. The edited title tries to get away from that and is a benefit yo you for that reason, but your question is still pretty much a request for a list of hardware that has a particular feature. I recommend you edit your question to finish getting away from this.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Chipset names and platforms define everything; and proprietary implementations quite often. Ignoring this in technical discussion is a pure sophism. It is like discussing an isotropic spherical horse in perfect vacuum. There is a limit to any depersonalization defined by the point when marketing starts. And the problem itself was defined 15~17 years ago, when the wake-up capable BT drivers were written by Microsoft. There is simply no place for marketing at this time.

Lets stop discussing Microsoft Windows, and Linux, because these are product names.